# Return all rows but aggregate some of them (and not others)

Tags: mysql, sql

Customer wants to distinguish between members of some categories, and does NOT want distinguish between the members of others. Data looks like this (lets call it TABLE1):

```
cola      colb     value
A          a1       10
A          a2       12
A          b2       25
B          zz       12
B          w2       14
```

The output that I want is all rows where cola = A just as they are in the source table, but I want to aggregate the rows where cola = B and ignore the values in colb for that value of cola. Output that is suitable looks like:

```
cola     colb      value
A        a1        10
A        a2        12
A        b2        25
B        all       26
```

Now, I've obtained the desired output (i.e., 'solved' the problem) using this query:

```
SELECT
    cola,
    'all',
    sum(value)
FROM TABLE1 T1
WHERE cola = 'B'
GROUP BY
    cola,
   'all'
UNION
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1 T2
WHERE cola != 'B'
```

But, 'TABLE1' is actually a UNION of 3 other views, and while this thing works, it looks ugly, seems 'brute force' to me, and feels clunky. Can you suggest a better way to think about the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple matter of using a `case` statement in the `group by`:

```
select cola,
       (case when cola = 'B' then 'all'
             else colb
        end),
       sum(value)
from TABLE1 T1
group by cola,
         (case when cola = 'B' then 'all'
               else colb
          end);
```

Comment: Solved. Another 'OMG' moment.